# Filter not-matching pivot table documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a database replicated in Elasticsearch (...). Given the following ...

Service

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | service1 |
| 2 | service2 |
| 3 | service3 |

Package

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | package1 |
| 2 | package2 |

PackageService (pivot)

| id | PackageId | ServiceId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |

I want to return documents where *"Packages reference only **these** services - excluding all packages that match anything else"*.

As an example, when I query `PackageService` with

```
{  
 bool
  must
   term
    ServiceId [1, 2]
}
```

I get back `package1` and `package2`. I don't want `package2`, because while it *does* reference `service1`, it also references `service3`.

The solution I've come up with is to run two queries. One as above, and another inverted, like

```
{  
 bool
  must_not
   term
    ServiceId [1, 2]
}
```

and then [array_diff (php)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) the two results `array_diff([1, 2], [1]) => [1]`, which is what I want.

Is there any way to do this with one query?

Note, I do not know about `service3` when I am making the queries, so I cannot simply include it in a `must_not`.